# How do I make a magic picture on Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I hope this doesn't violate the "Links to External Sites" rule, but I've played around with this and cannot seem to replicate the results: https://twitter.com/penguins/status/578255717880238080

Can someone explain how to do this, showing the steps?

Answer (score 4):

The effect takes advantage of the fact that the twitter timeline has a white background but a grey background when you hover over a tweet - and a black background when you click through to view an image. This is done by having a transparent image with only the white areas of the image showing - so you will only see anything when the grey or black background *fills in* the rest of the image.

**First get a black & white image.**

The first step is to make the image you want to use, black & white. Use the Black & White adjustment and get as much contrast as possible.

[image]
[image]

**Flatten the image. Select All then Copy.**

[image]

**Create a new solid color fill layer and set the color to white.**

Hide the original image. Then with the new color layer selected, add a layer mask. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the layer mask icon in the layers panel to directly edit the mask and paste the image in to the layer mask. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> the layer mask again to finish editing the mask.

[image]

**For the part of the image that is always visible** (in your example and here it is text, but it could be anything).

Create the text layer, then copy the original black & white image above the image and create a clipping mask with the image - either <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (with the image selected) or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> between the two layers in the layers panel.

[image]

**Save the image as a PNG with transparency enabled and you're good to go!**

This is the same image with the different backgrounds showing through:

[image]